# 'revised' displayed in red in activity tab on profile page after accepted edit

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, profile-page

I just noticed that on my profile page, under the activity tab, the word 'revised' is displayed in red when I make an edit. Seeing something in red text makes me think that something bad happened, but is actually a good thing that a post has been improved, right?

It is understandable that this text is displayed in red when a suggested edit has been rejected, but shouldn't the word 'revised' be displayed in green when an edit has been accepted?

Comment: Not all suggested edits are good. The red color is probably to notify that something has been changed in your post and that it needs your attention because in case its a bad/wrong/spam edit, then you need to roll it back asap. Ofcourse, if its good, you can just move on. Honestly, I would prefer that to be displayed in red than green or any other color for that matter.

Comment: Regarding "red is bad", it's better not to have this perception since per-site theme color can affect this (there was another post with long discussion about that which was heavily downvoted, and maybe already deleted). Meanwhile, I kind of support the idea that if it's accepted, then it's green.